# Issues with creating schema for a iceberg table using glue catalog

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create an iceberg table using glue catalog, But  I am having difficulties.
I tried multiple approaches but they did not work.

```
def get_s3_path(bucket_name: str, database_name: Optional[str] = None, table_name: Optional[str] = None) -> str:
    result_path = f"s3://{bucket_name}"
    if database_name is not None:
        result_path += f"/{database_name}.db"

    if table_name is not None:
        result_path += f"/{table_name}"
    return result_path

def get_bucket_name() -> str:
    return bucket_name

test_catalog = GlueCatalog(catalog_name, warehouse=get_s3_path(get_bucket_name()))

table_schema_nested = Schema(
            NestedField(field_id=1, name="column1", field_type=StringType()),
            NestedField(field_id=2, name="column2", field_type=IntegerType(), required=False),
        )


table_input = {
    "Name": f"{table_name}",
    "TableType": "EXTERNAL_TABLE",
    "PartitionKeys": [
        {"name": "column1", "Type": "string"},
    ],
    "Schema": Schema(
        NestedField(field_id=1, name="column1", field_type=StringType()),
    ),
    "StorageDescriptor": {
        "Location": f"s3://{bucket_name}/{table_name}",
        "Columns": [
            {"Name": "column1", "Type": "string"},
        ],
        "InputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.ParquetInputFormat",
        "OutputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.ParquetOutputFormat",
        "SerdeInfo": {"SerializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe"},
    },
}

def test_create_table(s3: boto3.client, table_schema_nested: Schema, table_name, database_name):
    identifier = (database_name, table_name)
    test_catalog = GlueCatalog(catalog_name, **{"py-io-impl": "pyiceberg.io.fsspec.FsspecFileIO"})
    test_catalog.create_namespace(namespace=database_name, properties={"location": f"s3://{bucket_name}/{database_name}"})
    table = test_catalog.create_table(
        identifier=identifier,
        schema=table_schema_nested,
        location=f"s3://{bucket_name}/{database_name}/{table_name}", properties=table_input
    )

glue_client = boto3.client('glue',
                           region_name=region,
                           aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                           aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

test_catalog.drop_namespace(database_name)
iceberg_table = test_create_table(glue_client, table_schema_nested, table_name, database_name)

response = glue_client.get_tables(DatabaseName=database_name)

data = [
    {'column1': 'Anurag'},
]


for item in data:
    response = glue_client.batch_create_partition(
        DatabaseName=database_name,
        TableName=f'{table_name}',
        PartitionInputList=[
            {
                'Values': [
                    str(item['column1']),
                ],
                'StorageDescriptor': {
                    'Location': f's3://{bucket_name}/{database_name}/{table_name}/part1',
                    'Columns': [
                        {'Name': 'column1', 'Type': 'string'},
                    ],
                    'SerdeInfo': {
                        'SerializationLibrary': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe',
                        'Parameters': {
                            'serialization.format': '1'
                        }
                    },
                    'InputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat',
                    'OutputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
                }
            }
        ]
    )
```

The above code returns error:
Currently, I am getting error from

> pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError:

The above code creates the table but no columns are added.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is schema_id field is valid or required? can you try without that argument and check? looking at documentation of pyiceberg i didn't find it. I might be wrong (or missed it) but if you confirm or direct me to docs that would help me too.thanks.

Comment: Please trim your code so as to include only hte relevant section ([mre])

Comment: @PoonamAdhav I removed schema_id but I still see the issue.

Comment: @OCa Trimmed my code a bit. I added methods which I used to reduce confusions.

Comment: Maybe rethink your tags, be more detailed and accurate. You are allowed up to 5. Iceberg? Glue?